# Why does my random number function always return same output?

Tags: javascript, function, random, numbers, closures

I have the following code:

```
var lives = 10;
var score = 0;
var input = $('#input');
var board = $('#board');
var validate = $('#validate');

function randomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var levelOne = (randomNum(0, 999));
var levelTwo = (randomNum(999, 1999));

$('#generate').click(function () {
    if (score > 1) {
        board.html(levelOne);
        console.log(levelOne)
        setTimeout(function () {
            board.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        board.html(levelTwo);
        console.log(levelTwo)
        setTimeout(function () {
            board.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

The first number gets it output as expected, but if I keep on generating numbers, the logs say it's the same number plus I can't see it in the screen (the timeout is not working as well?). I've done this game in Objective-C but now in JS something is missing in my logic. Can someone give me a hint?

EDIT: I've tried this

```
$('#generate').click(function () {
    var levelOne = (randomNum(0, 999));
    if (score > 1) {
        board.html(levelOne);
        console.log(levelOne)
        setTimeout(function () {
            board.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    } // etc
}
```

and also inside the `if`. I don't understand why I get always the same number.

Comment: The function you’re passing to `$('#generate').click()` runs when you click `#generate`. Are you setting `levelOne` and `levelTwo` inside or outside that function?

Comment: Outside. Is it a scope issue then?

Comment: The statement `var levelOne = (randomNum(0, 999));` means "get a single random number between 0 and 999, and then set the value of `levelOne` to that value."  It does not make `levelOne` an *alias* for "get a single random number".

Comment: I don't follow @Pointy

Comment: @Mellville well the code you posted only includes one call to `randomNum()`. Well two calls, but each only happens once.  When the "click" handler is called, no more random numbers are generated; it just looks at the original ones generated earlier.

Comment: So how can I solve this? I tried working on the scope, but the issue remains

Comment: Generate new random numbers **inside** the "click" handler.

Comment: (It isn’t a scope issue, it’s a “not doing the thing” issue. The variable holds a value and you never tell it to change the value it’s holding.)

Comment: i've tried `board.html(randomNum(0, 999));´ as Pointy suggested, but it doesnt work. the number is the same

Comment: Have you tried `levelOne = randomNum(0, 999);` **inside** the "click" handler? (And the same for `levelTwo`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're caching the variables `levelOne` and `levelTwo` outside of your click handler so random numbers are only generated once, if you're like them to be repeatedly regenerated put those lines inside your click handler like so:

```
var lives = 10;
var score = 0;
var input = $('#input');
var board = $('#board');
var validate = $('#validate');

function randomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$('#generate').click(function () {
    if (score > 1) {
        var levelOne = randomNum(0, 999);
        board.html(levelOne);
        console.log(levelOne)
        setTimeout(function () {
            board.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        var levelTwo = randomNum(999, 1999);
        board.html(levelTwo);
        console.log(levelTwo)
        setTimeout(function () {
            board.fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Mellville no, it wasn't a "scope" issue. Scope is about the visibility of symbols.